# Ruby State Machine - After or Before transition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, state

I am using the gem state_machines found here https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines

I have it setup so you can dynamically generate state flows via the web browser and also have a few pre determined events.  For example.  You can setup a before or after transition to fire and send and email.

Is there anyway to tell which transition is being fired i.e is it a before or after transition?

Thanks

Comment: you have two separate callbacks for before and after transition so you know from which particular method is fired

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  I know that much but I may be being a complete idiot here.  Say when a setup an after and before transition to hit the same method called email in the statemachine class.  Anyway to tell within the email method if its the after or before transition.